# slab_unreclaimable overtop and oom_kill [PID] process

Tags: kernel, ram

Below is my kernel log

```
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171352] Mem-Info:
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171357] active_anon:514088 inactive_anon:280946 isolated_anon:0
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171357]  active_file:247 inactive_file:1134 isolated_file:123
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171357]  unevictable:31537 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171357]  slab_reclaimable:18057 slab_unreclaimable:373525
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171357]  mapped:19912 shmem:59183 pagetables:742629 bounce:0
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171357]  free:26336 free_pcp:1351 free_cma:0
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171361] Node 0 active_anon:2056352kB inactive_anon:1123784kB active_file:988kB inactive_file:4536kB unevictable:126148kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):492kB mapped:79648kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB shmem:236732kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 0kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB all_unreclaimable? no
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171363] Node 0 DMA free:15888kB min:132kB low:164kB high:196kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15992kB managed:15888kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171368] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2116 7795 7795 7795
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171370] Node 0 DMA32 free:40392kB min:18316kB low:22892kB high:27468kB active_anon:297972kB inactive_anon:260848kB active_file:108kB inactive_file:1248kB unevictable:33480kB writepending:0kB present:2275704kB managed:2210016kB mlocked:32256kB kernel_stack:260kB pagetables:1060844kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:912kB local_pcp:224kB free_cma:0kB
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171374] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 5678 5678 5678
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171376] Node 0 Normal free:49064kB min:49132kB low:61412kB high:73692kB active_anon:1758380kB inactive_anon:862936kB active_file:1160kB inactive_file:4708kB unevictable:92668kB writepending:0kB present:5996544kB managed:5822328kB mlocked:49888kB kernel_stack:24860kB pagetables:1909672kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:4492kB local_pcp:856kB free_cma:0kB
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171381] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171383] Node 0 DMA: 2*4kB (U) 1*8kB (U) 2*16kB (U) 1*32kB (U) 3*64kB (U) 2*128kB (U) 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15888kB
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171390] Node 0 DMA32: 763*4kB (UME) 298*8kB (UME) 870*16kB (UME) 100*32kB (UME) 59*64kB (UE) 37*128kB (UE) 24*256kB (UE) 8*512kB (UE) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 41308kB
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171395] Node 0 Normal: 2145*4kB (UME) 2366*8kB (UME) 834*16kB (UME) 144*32kB (UME) 40*64kB (UME) 9*128kB (UME) 2*256kB (UE) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 49684kB
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171402] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171403] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171403] 84105 total pagecache pages
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171405] 22211 pages in swap cache
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171406] Swap cache stats: add 734033, delete 711823, find 375430/426343
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171407] Free swap  = -1123492kB
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171407] Total swap = 0kB
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171408] 2072060 pages RAM
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171408] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171409] 60002 pages reserved
Oct 29 10:34:34  kernel: [43384.171409] 0 pages cma reserved
...
Out of memory: Killed process 4418 (robot_sensing_s) total-vm:644708848kB, anon-rss:264464kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:1257132kB oom_score_adj:0
```

I find slab_unreclaimable:373525 , is overtop , maybe it is the reason of killing my process

But I do not know which process has a memory leak,  Hope to get everyone's help , thanks.

Comment: What does `top` / `htop` say about memory usage? It should be quite easy to monitor which processes consume lots of memory.

Comment: I tried,  can not find the processes , I suspect if some processes be hidden

Comment: I aim to find which process consume the slab_unreclaimable memory, I can not find the terminal command